# How to delete IndexedDB old version of database by js?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I use creation of indexedDB like this

```
  var getIndexedDB = function() {
  if ( !indexedDB ) {
    indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.oIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || ((window.indexedDB === null && window.shimIndexedDB) ? window.shimIndexedDB : undefined);

    if ( !indexedDB ) {
      throw 'IndexedDB required';
    }
  }
  return indexedDB;
};
```

On deployment changing the version of database. But if look into size of files (where saving browser indexedDB) they add a new data and not deleting old. 
Need by js check if indexedDB has databases with old version and drop (by js!) only old versions (not all database).

Answer (score 5):

**Some starting bytes:**
Using the `getIndexedDB()` you mentioned, you will only get the holder of IDB, it will not open a database for storage. You need to use below code for opening a IDB instance:

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION, {storage: "temporary"});
```

Also, personally I would NOT recommend using IDB prefixes like `webkitIndexedDB`, `mozIndexedDB`, until you have some real good reason for using prefixes. Read more about [IDB prefix from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)

> Beware that implementations that use a prefix may be buggy, or
>   incomplete, or following an old version of the specification.

**Deleting IDB instance:**
Once you have opened a database, you can delete the database using `IDBFactory.deleteDatabase()`, read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory/deleteDatabase).

But please note that if there are 2 tabs opened for same application which means 2 IDB instance of same database, then you cannot delete database because db instance will go into blocked state. You can try using `deleteDatabase()` and you will see that database delete operation will not work until you close other tab. Try using below code and you will database goes in blocked state, also below is the how to delete IDB database using JS code.

```
var DBDeleteRequest = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase("toDoList");
DBDeleteRequest.onblocked = function(event) {
    alert("Error message: Database in blocked state. ");
};
DBDeleteRequest.onerror = function(event) {
  console.log("Error deleting database.");
};

DBDeleteRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  console.log("Database deleted successfully");

  console.log(request.result); // should be null
};
```

**IDB versions:**
I would personally not recommend changing IDB version each time you do a new deployment otherwise user browser will end up having hell lot of IDB instance.

Versions in IDB is mainly to support the runtime time manipulation of IDB schema. Suppose you want to add some new column/store, remove some index from existing store etc. then you should increase the version by one and do db schema manipulation.

Clear browser cache and `IDBFactory.deleteDatabase()` are 2 mechanism to delete IDB instance.

Below is how you can handle open and delete IDB but we aware that you should/can use `localStorage` in conjunction with it to check when you just need to open a database and when delete + open.

```
     var dbDeleteRequest = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase("toDoList");
    dbDeleteRequest.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("Error while deleting database.", true);
    };

    dbDeleteRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log("Success while deleting database.", true);
        // Let us open our database
        var DBOpenRequest = window.indexedDB.open("toDoList", 5);

        DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
          console.log('<li>Database initialised.</li>');
        };

        DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
          console.log('<li>DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded</li>');
        };
    };
```

Comment: **getIndexedDB** need to support old browser versions. In your solution will be deleted _all_ database and then created a new one, I need to delete _only old versions database_. We don't know what a versions was before. Need somthing like this: ``

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement, probably taking by example what is present version, how it updates, then what you delete ..

Comment: `window.indexedDB.getDatabaseNames().onsuccess = function(sender,args){
    var namesList = sender.target.result;    
    for(var i in namesList)
    {
        var db = window.indexedDB.open(namesList[i]);
        var versionList = db.getVersionNames();
        for( var n in versionList){
             if(versionList[n]<localStorage.getItem('version')){
                     window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(namesList[i],versionList[n]);
             }
        }
    }
};`

Comment: I don't understand how and why you want to delete based on version number .. In IDB you cannot delete database based on version number .. Database is deleted based on database name .. Check the IDB deleteDatabase link I provided, there is no valid argument in `indexedDB.deleteDatabase()` to accept version number, it accepts only 2 argument - database name and storage type .. You may need to consider other option to delete database, try one I provided ..

Comment: I hv implemented a IDB and WebSQL adapter and personally I have never came across `window.indexedDB.getDatabaseNames()` .. I don't know how it is working for you .. Hv you created a prototype for it or something ??

Comment: It's not working. Because existing function _webkitGetDatabaseNames()_ not for all browsers. No way to get list of databases for all borwsers? The second problem how to get list of versions by database? The third problem how to delete only one of version and not all of database.I don't want to change all functionality that already exists, only delete not actual versions of indexedDB.

Comment: Unfortunately as per best of my knowledge answers to all your question is "no". Due to privacy reason you cannot get list of all existing IDB database names. **IDB implements same origin policy rules**, so another other application has no chance of getting it and even application who created a list of IDB instances cannot get a list of database names or versions.

Comment: Could you please explain what is your requirement. I don't understand why you want to delete some database versions?

Comment: I have many users, each user has his own database with html templates. On each deploying templates may be changed. That is why on new version on production changing version of database. If template not exist in database then will be ajax request to server get another one. After some time users will be have not useful data on his hard drive.

Comment: Ideal situation is that user should clear the cache so that your new changes can take effect .. If user is clearing the cache then there should be no issue in using same version of database and if user is not clearing cache then how your need HTML/JS files will be reflected in his browser .. My suggestion - go for delete + open database option, see last code snippet in my answer .. As per me, what you are trying to achieve is not possible because there is no such API in IDB which gives you list of database names and db version based deletion .. Feel free to let me know if any doubt ..

Answer (score 0):

In my case solution before open a new connection for work check if existing version is actual. If not actual delete all database before open a new connection.

```
function deleteOldIndexedDB(dbName, actualVersion){
     if(!indexedDB){
          return false;
     }

    var req = indexedDB.open(dbName);
    req.onsuccess = function(event)
    {
        var version;
        if(event.srcElement != undefined){
            version = event.srcElement.result.version;//chrome
        }else{
            version = event.target.result.version;//firefox
        }

        event.target.result.close();
        if(version != actualVersion && version != 1){                
            indexedDB.deleteDatabase(dbName);
        }
    };
}
```